# Increasing web page's original height causes on back navigation to change the scroll position

Tags: angular, web, navigation

I have a website where I list a bunch of products in a list view. I show only 30 products and I have a show more button below the products. Clicking it will show the user 30 more products and it will also expand the page. If were to click on a product and then click on the back button the selected product is opened and then the page brings us back to the position on the list where the product was clicked. If the same action is repeated after the show more button has been clicked, the page navigates back to the footer area.

What is the issue here and how can this be fixed? I store the number of clicks on the show more button in a state so the number of displayed products is correct, yet it still navigates to the footer.

Comment: It's hard to say without stackblitz repro, but most probably you're loading the products asynchronously, so the scrolling happens before you load and render more products. Then, when new ones are loaded, the screen "sticks" to the position it was scrolled to. You will need to store the position of the scrollbar and then manually scroll to that position after all the items have been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Return to the previous position

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Custom scrolling records

```
  constructor(private router: Router, private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((e: Scroll) => e instanceof Scroll)
    ).subscribe(
      e => {
        if (e.position) {
          // retreat
          viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
        } else if (e.anchor) {
          // hash
          viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
        } else {
          // forward navigation
          viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
        }
      }
    )
  }
```